# ajax responseText is returning header bar with echo content

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I am using `ajax` to communicate with `PHP`.When fetched data shows that typed email is present on database,I used `echo` with message 'email is already taken,try another email'.But `ajax responseText` is returning `header file and echoed content`.Here is a image

[image]

How can I just get echoed message as ajax responseText?

Here are my codes

**Javascript**

```
function signup(){
  var f=document.getElementById("firstname").value;
  var l=document.getElementById("lastname").value;
  var p=document.getElementById("password1").value;
  var p2=document.getElementById("password2").value;
  var e=document.getElementById("email").value;
  var status=document.getElementById("status");

  if(f=="" || l=="" || p=="" || p2=="" || e==""){
     status.innerHTML="All fields are required";
  }
  else if(p!=p2){
     status.innerHTML="passwords didn't match";
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("submitX").style.display = "none";
    //status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("POST","signup.php",true);
    x.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    x.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
     if(x.responseText != "success"){  //this condition is not met at any circumstances
         document.getElementById("submitX").style.display = "block";
         status.innerHTML="";
         //alert(x.responseText);
         status.innerHTML = x.responseText;
        }
       else{
         window.scrollTo(0,0);
         status.innerHTML ="";
         document.getElementById("diff_for").innerHTML = "";
         document.getElementById("form1").innerHTML = "";
         document.getElementById("form1").innerHTML = "Thank you for creating an account.A Welcome email has been sent to your email.<br/><br/>Go to <a href='login.php'>Login</a>";

     }

    }
   }
  x.send("F="+f+"&L="+l+"&E="+e+"&P="+p+"&P2="+p2);
 }
}
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['F'])){
  $firstname=$_POST['F'];
  $lastname=$_POST['L'];
  $password=$_POST['P'];
  $passmatch=$_POST['P2'];
  $pass=md5($password);
  $email=$_POST['E'];

 $sqlx1="SELECT id FROM user_det WHERE email=? LIMIT 1";

   mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt30, $sqlx1);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt30, "s", $email);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt30);
   mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt30);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt30, $idx1);
   $num_row1x=mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt30);

     if($num_row1x>0){
       //ob_end_clean();
       //ob_start();
       $abul="<br>This email is already registered.Please use another email";
       echo $abul;
       exit();
     }
     else{
       $sql11x="INSERT INTO user_det(first_name,last_name,password,email,signup_date)
               VALUES(?,?,?,?,now())";

       mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt30, $sql11x);
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt30, "ssss", $firstname, $lastname, $pass, $email);
       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt30);                   

       echo "success";
     }
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean that it is returning the header file and associated content. It seems like its okay to me? It is echoing exactly what you wrote. Maybe i'm not undertanding. Could you please explain in more detail

Comment: I just need to get `This email is already taken.......` from `x.responseText`.but it is returning `<html><head><style>.....<div id='bar'></div></head></html><br>This email is already taken.Please use another email` when I use `alert` to see response.I need only echoed message so that I can do `if else` for response text

Comment: @CarlSaldanha I first felt like you. But I now understand that "header file" is the black bar with something like "Wagall". It features at the top of the screenshot, then also at the bottom of the mobile-like part, just before the expected message. But I can't figure out where it comes from...

Comment: @cFreed exactly.You got it right

Comment: Ohh. Thanks cFreed. @Coder. Have you imported any PHP into the above code or is the code the ENTIRE file. Also are you using any PHP frameworks or is this pure PHP

Comment: I have included `top_bar.php` on top of `signup.php`.And,I'm using pure `PHP`.No Framework

Comment: Not sure if it's affecting anything but, try removing the `<br>` in the message.

Comment: pretty sure `<br>` is not affecting,but still tried it after removing.But still the same

Answer (score 0):

With your additional comment, now I see what's happening.

It is not visible with only the partial PHP code you posted, and you should post the whole code if not too heavy.

But it's pretty sure that your error resides somewhere near the top of your PHP file: when you test `if(isset($_POST['F'])){` you have already output the begin of the original page, which is generated by the same PHP file.

BTW, you should also ensure to `exit;` after echoing message responding to Ajax call.

Comment: I have included `top_bar.php`(that black bar on top) on top of `signup.php` file.Is it causing the trouble?

Comment: I did use `exit()` after echoing msg for ajax response

Comment: You din't indicate the names of the parts of code you've posted. So I'm not sure of anything, but guess that `sign.up` is the name of the PHP part you posted. If so, yes, it's the reason of your problem. This PHP file does exactly what you "want", so if `top_bar.php` outputs a content, it is part of what is returned to the Ajax call.

Comment: @ your second comment (did use `exit;`). Oh yes, I see it after the main message. But it's NOT after the last `echo "success"`.

Comment: I have tested using `exit()` after success msg.But still giving same result.Any idea,what's going on?

Comment: But I didn't say the lack of `exit;` was the cause of the current problem: it's only an advice to have this rule in any case, against other possible problems. Fro the curent one, as I said previously, it's du to the output of `top_bar.php`.

Comment: Thanks for ur response.Is there any way,I can tell the child `signup.php` to stop including parent `top_bar.php` file just before `if(isset($_POST['F'])){`?Thanks

Comment: What we need is not "just before `if(isset($_POST['F'])){`. At the opposite, you must first test `if(isset($_POST['F'])){` so to NOT include `top_bar.php` BUT ONLY do the job like the code you posted, in the TRUE part of this condition. And in the FALSE part (or simply after the condition end, assumed you properly have `exit;`s where needed), you may quietly do anything else, regarding your main page... like including `top_bar.php`.